# convert html carousel in dynamic php carousel

Tags: php

i have a carousel that i want to change in dynamic carousel, the html structure is as following:

```
 <div class="item active">
    <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
 </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
 </div>
```

first div have class `active` after that second div dont have `active` class and after every 4 div inside item class with demo data the `item` class div closes and new div open with `item` class how to do it

Here is my php code:

```
<?php $a=1; while($rfc=$resfc->fetch_array()) { if($a<=4){?>
     <!-- starts carousel -->
     <div class="item active"><?php } else {?> <div class="item"> <?php } ?>
          <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
      </div>

 <?php $a++; }}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you need:

```
<?php 
     $a=1; while($rfc=$resfc->fetch_array()) { 

     $active = ($a == 1) ? 'active' : ''; // set active or empty string

     echo '<!-- starts carousel -->
     <div class="item ' . $active . '">
          <div class="col-md-3">demo</div>
      </div>';

     if ($a % 4 == 0) {  // if it evenly divides by 4 with no remainder, add the closing and opening divs
        echo '</div><div class="item">';
     }
     $a++; }}
```

Comment: That would print only one `<div class="col-md-3">demo</div>` in a `<div class="item">`

Comment: and what about content inside the item class div. i have 4 div inside it

Comment: kerbholz he can put whatever he wants inside the loop, The code sample he showed us only has one inside.  I'm just showing the easiest way to set the active class and the closing divs every 4 iterations.